# scanf("%s") stores string even after using it after scanf("%d")

Tags: c, scanf

So I wrote this code(ignore the buffer overflow problem as this is just a simple example):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int n;
    char s[10];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
}
```

The string shouldn't get stored in the array because there should be a "\n" in the input buffer and hence the scanf("%s",s) should be terminated but it is not the case. The output prints the string.

Comment: @xing Thank you very much. I didn't knew that.

Comment: Usually, it only causes problems for a subsequent `"%c"` format specifier, which does not automatically skip leading whitespace, unless specifically instructed to with `" %c"`.

Comment: "...because there should be a "\n" in the input buffer..."  - where did you get that idea? `scanf` does not care about `\n` at all. For `scanf` `\n` is just another whitespace character.

Comment: @AnT scanf does care about whitespaces with %c, %n and %[

Answer (score 3):

Format specifier `%s` skips leading whitespaces, i.e. any `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'`,... will be ignored and `s[0]` will contain the first non-whitespace of the input.

To demonstrate a little bit whats going on in `scanf`, see the following example that makes use of the `"%n"`-feature of `scanf`, which gives back the number of characters that have been processed so far; And I used `sscanf` such that the result does not depend on user input. Note that when reading in the string, `scanf` processes more characters than stored in the result:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int n;
    int pos;
    char s[10];
    const char* simulatedInput = "123\n     abcde";
    const char* inputPtr = simulatedInput;

    sscanf(inputPtr,"%d%n",&n,&pos);
    printf("sscanf on %s processed %d charaters; result n: %d\n", inputPtr, pos, n);

    inputPtr += pos;  // inputPtr will point at the position of '\n'
    sscanf(inputPtr,"%s%n",s,&pos);
    printf("sscanf on %s processed %d charaters; yet s as '%s' contains only %lu characters\n", inputPtr, pos, s, strlen(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sscanf on 123
     abcde processed 3 charaters; result n: 123
sscanf on 
     abcde processed 11 charaters; yet s as 'abcde' contains only 5 characters
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick: The POSIX specification of [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html), in a section not marked as a POSIX extension, says that 'white space' includes form feed `'\f'` and vertical tab `'\v'` as well as blank, tab and newline.  That's not a major issue; you seldom encounter either.  ('Tis curious that the C standard adds carriage return `'\r'` to the list of characters recognized by `isspace()` in the default (C) locale.  The C standard says 'white space' without listing the characters; that implies "what `isspace()` says is white space".)